# How to reinstall apache server again if deleted?

Tags: macos, apache, reinstall

Here is a challenge.
If apache server is deleted from mac, how will you reinstall it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install Apache web server with Homebrew, by executing the following command:

```
brew install httpd
```